# How to access/modify data using dstore Request

Tags: dojo, dstore

The documentation for dstore Request says...
Request - This is a simple server-based collection that sends HTTP requests following REST conventions to access and modify data requested through the store interface.

How does one access and modify the data if get, put, add and remove are not implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dstore/Request` simply implements fetch logic.  For full interaction with REST APIs, you will want to use `dstore/Rest`, which extends it with the methods you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. In that case someone should edit the documentation.